# Stimulsoft Reports : Print each Group on a single Page?

Tags: report, stimulsoft

I am creating a report with Stimulsoft. I have a GroupHeader Band and a GroupFooter Band which have a condition. The report works just fine but I need my report to print each Group on a separate Page. Is there any way to break the report into separate Pages based on different Groups ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an easy answer to this question. On GroupHeader Band properties, we need to set "New Page Before" property to "True" so each Group will be printed on a separate Page. That's it !

Comment: How can I generate multiple reports in a single file using Stimul Reports , C# ?[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53059209/8315608)  **Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

You also can set the "New Page After" of Group Footer, to true